# Easily record and then share computer screen

Tags: windows, screen-recording, sharing, screen-sharing

I am looking for a free or not Windows 10 software to easily and quickly record my computer screen and share it trough a platform like Discord without bothering with video encoding and stuff. Having a compressed output would be great since the idea is to send the video to someone. Any common video output is okay, mp4, avi, etc. The ability to select screen region is a plus.

There are plenty of great tools that allow instant sharing for screenshots. For example I use Lightshot and I just need to CTRL + C a screen region and then CTRL + V through a Discord channel and done. But I struggle to find something that would act almost that easily (I am not talking about copying/pasting video to a chat obviously).

https://medal.tv/ seemed great but unfortunately only allow in-game recording and I want to be able to record my desktop.

Comment: @shellwhale So in a nutshell you want to record a few seconds of your screen and then be able to post them into a chat. How long are the "videos" going to be? A few seconds up to a minute? Is GIF an acceptable output? Is upload to imgur or similar services acceptable as well?

Comment: Up to a minute would be great. GIF is okay but there may be a few times where I would want to have the audio as well.Ability to auto host the image to a service like imgur or giphy would just be bonus at this point.

Comment: @shellwhale Do you have a youtube account, would you be willing to store any videos to your youtube account?

Comment: Youtube is okay but only if I'm still allowed to keep a local file of the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shellwhale thanks for answering my questions to your OP.

A good solution for you would be [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) with FFMPEG to allow you to capture videos

It allows you to grab screenshots, GIFs and videos easily.

Also if you have a look at the destinations frame below it allows you to upload to imgur, youtube or a plethora of other online storage services.

You can also set it to automatically do tasks after the capture such as upload it to a certain host or you can do it manually.

I believe it can also paste the link of the uploaded media to your clipboard. So you can actually just record wait for a few seconds and then hit Ctrl+V on the chat.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I developed the utility in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.utilityspotlight2.aspx. But it has some issues with Win 10. So I corrected them and published at https://burakuysaler.wordpress.com/2020/03/16/screenrecorder-final-by-burak-uysaler/. As I don’t work at Microsoft anymore, I uploaded it to my Blog. Please try it, You will love it :)

Comment: Note to all: This brand new Software Recommendations SE community member quickly posted this recommendation multiple times.  Please use caution if visiting the specified site and trying the recommended software.  Please add comments if your experiences are positive or negative. Thank you.